# VERBO: Créeme y Cree en mí

Tags: uso-de-palabras

Se puede decir:

> Por favor, créeme.

o

> Por favor, cree en mí.

Las dos formas son correctas, ¿no?
¿Cuál es la diferencia?

Answer (score 5):

Las dos formas son correctas, pero el significado puede ser bien diferente.

"Créeme" en general significa "créeme lo que estoy diciendo"

mientras que:

"Cree en mí" en general significa "ten confianza en mí".